# Counting the maximum number of paths of length $n$ that differ in at least $k$ edges

Tags: graph-algorithms, np-hardness, approximation-algorithms

What is known about the complexity of solving (or approximately solving) the following problem?

INPUT: Graph $G=(V,E)$ and constants $L$ and $K$.

OUTPUT: The maximum size of any set $S$ of simple paths of length $L$ such that every two paths in $S$ differ in at least $K$ edges. I care about the case when $L$ and $K$ are small constants

Comment: So this is a variant of "maximum edge-disjoint paths"

Comment: Yes, but requiring at least k matches in two paths

Comment: If you can count the number of paths of length $n$ in polynomial time then you can solve Hamiltonian path problem. Is there a bound on the length of paths? I mean is $n$ a fixed value or it is part of input?

Comment: Saeed in my case $n$ and $d$ are both fixed and the graph is known. I just need to count how many of these paths are there